# Questions about Jinn/Evil Eye

Tags: jinn

Salam brothers & sisters

For 3 days now I haven’t been sleeping very well. I feel like at night someone is in my room and I feel like sometimes I hear noises or whispering but can’t make out what it is. Also there’s a few times I felt someone blowing cold air in my face. I have read Surah al bakara, Ayatul Kursk and the last 3 surahs in the Quran. I admit that I don’t pray regularly and I’ve only been reciting duas and listening to the Quran before I sleep. I still feel like there is someone in the room and feel scared at night sleeping alone so I sleep with the lights on.

On top of that for the last 5yrs I have been suffering from stress, depression and anxiety. Low mood and low energy. I procrastinate a lot and my concentration and memory is poor. I don’t like being around anyone and don’t feel motivated. I eat a lot of junk food and my hair falls out a lot. I also don’t sleep very well.

Should I go and get Rukya done ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better life in this life and the Hereafter, before anything else, you must pray all of your salahs on time. First of all, it is the most important action to be successful in the Akhirah. The Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings be upon him) said:

“Indeed the first deed by which a servant will be called to account on the Day of Resurrection is his Salat. If it is complete, he is successful and saved, but if it is defective, he has failed and lost.” (Tirmidhi 413) https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:413

Salah is also important for protection, which includes protection from the jinn. The Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings be upon him) said:

“Whoever offers the morning prayer, he is under the protection of Allah, the Mighty and Sublime.” (Ibn Majah 3946) https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3946

After you have established the prayers and you are regularly praying them on time, if you still have these experiences, you should do ruqyah on yourself. This can be done in many ways. One is to recite various Surahs, like Fatihah and the last 3 surahs, blow/spit on your hands and rub it on yourself. You can also do this to water (preferably zamzam) and drink or do ghusl with that water. Do this with olive oil as well and rub it on yourself. This works because the Quran is a cure. You should do this regularly until the symptoms go away.

You can get ruqyah done if you would like, but doing ruqyah on yourself is better. If you do get ruqyah done, ensure this person is doing things based on the sunnah and is not making things up. If you see him whispering strange things you don’t understand, using lockets with numbers or shapes, or doing anything not from the sunnah, stay away from this person and find someone who will do ruqyah properly, as those who use other means may make things worse or may even be using magic.